# HUE Query editor giving error for "dfs command"

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hue

For the below query:

[image]

**Error:**

> OK
>   FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'dfs' '-' 'cp'

[image]

Can anyone please guide me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put your source and destination urls between single qoutation. Like below:

```
dfs -cp path/to/your/source path/to/your/destination
```